# python copy os.system. resulting file is empty

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple progam to read and write a txt file in python:

```
import os

with open("1.txt") as infile,open("2.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)

####problem####
    os.system("cp 2.txt 3.txt")
####problem####
```

The resulting file "2.txt" is fine, but "3.txt" is empty. Can anyone give a solution for this.

1.txt simply contains two words:

```
two
words
```

Comment: de-indent the call to `os` allowing the flushing of the file and try again.

Comment: I have oversimplified the problem. I have been using this scheme to copy the resulting files to different destinations without a problem. I have seen this problem for the first time today. I just want to know the reason..

Comment: You didnt close the filehandles before calling your os functions. So file 2 is "empty" when you call `cp` and only gets "filled" after the `with` block finishes and closes the handle for you. (basically what Ev. Kounis said.)

Comment: thanks! that helped!